# WordPress transient not working with WP Engine

Tags: php, cache, transient, curl

For some reason, when we we're on another server (Tierpoint) everything worked fine and we recently switched over to WP Engine and the transients that I was using for my module have stopped working. Below, I will go into detail on both without and with transients.

**WITHOUT Transients**:

```
<?php
    /* Call the cURL request to pull in Instagram images */
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/". get_option('insta_id') ."/media?fields=media_url,permalink,username,media_type,thumbnail_url&access_token=". get_option('insta_accesstoken'));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $array = json_decode($result, true);
?>

<?php
/* Loop through the array and only pull API fields */
$mediaUrls = array_map(function($entry) {
    return [
        'media_url' => $entry['media_url'],
        'permalink' => $entry['permalink'],
        'username' => $entry['username'],
        'media_type' => $entry['media_type'],
        'thumbnail_url' => !empty($entry['thumbnail_url']) ? $entry['thumbnail_url'] : ""
    ];
}, $array['data']);
?>
```

Media loads on every refresh of the website (Other html elements have not been included) - Works great:
[image]

---

**WITH Transients**:

```
<?php $cached_result = get_transient('instagram');

if(empty($cached_result)): ?>
    <?php
    /* Call the cURL request to pull in Instagram images */
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/". get_option('insta_id') ."/media?fields=media_url,permalink,username,media_type,thumbnail_url&access_token=". get_option('insta_accesstoken'));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $array = json_decode($result, true);
    set_transient('instagram', $result, 8 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS);
    ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php return $cached_result; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
/* Loop through the array and only pull API fields */
$mediaUrls = array_map(function($entry) {
    return [
        'media_url' => $entry['media_url'],
        'permalink' => $entry['permalink'],
        'username' => $entry['username'],
        'media_type' => $entry['media_type'],
        'thumbnail_url' => !empty($entry['thumbnail_url']) ? $entry['thumbnail_url'] : ""
    ];
}, $array['data']);
?>
```

It writes to the database:
[image]

.. but all that I get back is a blank screen as shown below:
[image]

Is this a caching issue? Am I not doing something right with the transient?

Comment: Since this issue only happens on WP-Engine, I would highly recommend contacting their support team. They're the best people to investigate and will have access to adjust any configuration needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like they don't handle code issues (which is what their claiming) - It has to be a caching issue.. hmm.

Comment: In the `else`, shouldn't there be a `$array = $cached_result;` ? Why the `return` there?

Comment: @SallyCJ, that gives me an 'Illegal string offset 'data' error.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `$array = json_decode( $cached_result );`

Comment: @SallyCJ, thanks so much for helping out but I don't know if it's gonna end up working out - It's giving me the following error 'Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in'

Comment: What's weird is that I haven't had a issue with the return at all until recently, unsure what might have gone wrong.

Comment: `json_decode( $cached_result, true )` should work.

Comment: @SallyCJ, FIXED! Worked like a champ, thanks so much! Post it as the answer if you'd like so I can upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't know why the `return $cached_result;` in the `else`, but if that's intentional, then you should probably do:

```php
return json_decode( $cached_result, true );
```

Because you're caching the response *body* (which is a [JSON *string*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El3fc.png)) and you're reading the non-cached result like so: `$array = json_decode($result, true);`.

But if that `return` was a mistake, then this part:

```php
<?php else: ?>
    <?php return $cached_result; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Should be written as:

```php
<?php else: ?>
    <?php $array = json_decode( $cached_result, true ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```